# Neo4j aggregation and sum

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

I apologies if my question is trivial i am a NOOB at neo4j.

I am trying to write a cypher query that will find all the purple nodes desc order from the value of [sum ( mass_of * contains ) for all paths going from purple to red ]

example:
In picture it would be [( mass_of * contains )] for all red paths then sum all the red paths.

I started with this query but i m not sure where to go from here.

```
MATCH p0=(p:Purple)-[m:mass_of]->(g:Green)-[c:contains]->(r:red {name: "something"})
WITH m, c.amount * m.amount as total_per_path
WITH total_per_path, reduce( total=0, node IN collect(m)| total + total_per_path) AS total_something
RETURN total_something as TOTAL, total_per_path as PER_TOTAL_PATH
```

...

thanks for any help.

Comment: So it seems like your query is mostly there, but I don't understand why you're doing that `collect` on the basis of `m` - that bit is confusing because `m` is a relationship, but then you're saying `node in collect(m)` which doesn't really make sense, and then in the expression after it you're not using `node`.   So it seems like `total_per_path` mostly has what you want....why not sum all of the `total_per_path` variables?

Comment: I did the sum on `total_per_path` but that sums all the oranges and all the red paths. I want to have the sum for all the red paths and the sum for all the orange paths. I was trying to collect by `m` because it's represents a path ( but that does not seam quite right )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
MATCH (p:Purple)-[m:mass_of]->(g:Green)-[c:contains]->(r:red {name: "something"})
RETURN p, SUM(c.amount * m.amount) AS total
ORDER BY total DESC
```

You can also collect the m,g or c in return if you need that nodes/relationships.